# Mylyn Trac connector does not show "Severity" attribute in query editor

Tags: eclipse, trac, mylyn

We recently decided to start using the `Severity` field in our Trac project. However, I can't figure out a way to make the field appear in the query editor for the Mylyn plugin to Eclipse - whatever I try, the field is not there.

It does show up in the web interface, and if I open a task in Mylyn I can set a severity there (so at some point Mylyn *does* understand that the attribute is being used) but it doesn't appear in the query dialog.

I have

- Made sure all tasks have a severity set.
- Restarted Eclipse
- Synchronized with the repository
- Hit "Update attributes from repository" several times
- Reinstalled Mylyn

without success. What more is there to try?

**Clarification:** This is not about editing tickets. It's about *querying* tickets from the repository, using right-click in the task list -> "new query...".

This is what the form I see looks like:

[image]

I want a field for the severity in there somewhere too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to obtain the source for the TracQueryPage.java and add the list for "severity".

1. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6.2/org.eclipse.mylyn.trac/ui/3.4.2/org/eclipse/mylyn/internal/trac/ui/wizard/TracQueryPage.java?av=f
2. Create an empty plugin project in Eclipse (e.g. named trac-connector-patch)
3. Locate the org.eclipse.mylyn.trac.ui_3.6.0.v20110608-1400.jar in the plugin folder and copy the MANIFEST.MF to the plugin project's META-INF folder. Remove all lines starting with "Name:" and "SHA1-Digest:", then change Bundle-Symbolic-Name to

   Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.trac.ui-patched;singleton:=true
4. Copy the source for TracQueryPage.java into the source folder as

   src\org\eclipse\mylyn\internal\trac\ui\wizard\TracQueryPage.java
5. Fix the projects build path:

   - remove the exports from the MANIFEST.MF for org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.trac.ui and org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.trac.ui.editor
   - use the context menu "PDE Tools -> update classpath"
   - if there are still errors for org.eclipse.swt stuff, add the swt jar from the eclipse plugin folder as external jar to the projects build bpath (e.g. org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.7.1.v3738a.jar)
6. Modify the TracQueryPage

   ```
   // add a new list search field
   private ListSearchField severityField;
   ...

   protected Control createTicketAttributes(Composite control) {
       Composite group = new Composite(control, SWT.NONE);
       GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();

       layout.numColumns = 5; // add a column

       group.setLayout(layout);
       GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
       gd.horizontalSpan = 1;
       group.setLayoutData(gd);

       Label label = new Label(group, SWT.LEFT);
       label.setText(Messages.TracQueryPage_Status);

       label = new Label(group, SWT.LEFT);
       label.setText(Messages.TracQueryPage_Resolution);

       label = new Label(group, SWT.LEFT);
       label.setText(Messages.TracQueryPage_Type);

       label = new Label(group, SWT.LEFT);
       label.setText(Messages.TracQueryPage_Priority);

       label = new Label(group, SWT.LEFT);
       label.setText("Severity"); // TODO use a property

       statusField = new ListSearchField("status"); //$NON-NLS-1$
       statusField.createControls(group, STATUS_HEIGHT);

       resolutionField = new ListSearchField("resolution"); //$NON-NLS-1$
       resolutionField.createControls(group, STATUS_HEIGHT);

       typeField = new ListSearchField("type"); //$NON-NLS-1$
       typeField.createControls(group, STATUS_HEIGHT);

       priorityField = new ListSearchField("priority"); //$NON-NLS-1$
       priorityField.createControls(group, STATUS_HEIGHT);

       // add the severityField
       severityField = new ListSearchField("severity"); //$NON-NLS-1$
       severityField.createControls(group, STATUS_HEIGHT);

       return group;
   }

   private void updateAttributesFromRepository(final boolean force) {
       ...

       statusField.setValues(client.getTicketStatus());
       resolutionField.setValues(client.getTicketResolutions());
       typeField.setValues(client.getTicketTypes());
       priorityField.setValues(client.getPriorities());

       // also update the severities
       severityField.setValues(client.getSeverities());

       componentField.setValues(client.getComponents());
       versionField.setValues(client.getVersions());
       milestoneField.setValues(client.getMilestones());    
   }
   ```
7. Now you are ready to path the plugin jar (e.g. org.eclipse.mylyn.trac.ui_3.6.0.v20110608-1400.jar):

   - overwrite the TracQueryPage.class with your modified class
   - remove the "Name:" and "SHA1-Digest:" lines for the TracQueryPage.class from the MANIFEST.MF
8. Replace the plugin with your patched plugin. And restart eclipse.
9. Or download an already patched plugin: http://franke.ms/download/org.eclipse.mylyn.trac.ui_3.6.0.v20110608-1400-patched.zip

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it appears it is not possible to query based on severity. You may want to open a feature request at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs. Even better would be if you provided a patch. :)

Answer (score -1):

It does not have a labeled field in the form editor, but there is an icon next to the name. Clicking on that icon you can define the severity.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for the misundestanding. I don't know then the answer.